# Trying to make the thumbnail img of a video be responsive

Tags: css, html

When a user uploads a video on my site it shows a still img of the video which is currently set to 160px by 160px. All my other elements are responsive except for video img. What could i write to get a more responsive design?

This is the code that controls that element:

```
.video_thumb_wrapper {
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
float: left;
margin-bottom: 2px;
background: #666;
width: 160px;
height: 160px;
border: 4px solid;
}
```

[Showing page with video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHbNc.jpg)

Comment: Try doing width: 100% and height: 100% and see what happens. It's difficult to know for sure, without having a working example to go on. That's a good start though.

Comment: Doesn't work tried that.

Comment: Can you add more code we can work off of? It depends on if your img is inside another element or wrapper. You may need to set the width and height of that element to get it to work.

Comment: Do you want this video to be centered? Is there any positioning you need to maintain?